# How to manage isolated/dedicated iSCSI network?

Tags: switch, vlan, iscsi

This is more of iSCSI switch setup question.

I have an isolated iSCSI storage network which includes 2ea managed switches, and setup for redundancy.

I could just connect a management pc to one of these switches and setup proper static IP on same subnet.  This will allow me to manage the switches and the NAS.

But I want to manage this iSCSI network from my LAN network on different subnet.

I'm thinking I would have to create a VLAN for iSCSI network, uplink iSCSI switches to my LAN, and setup vlan routing so that my computer can access iSCSI network.
This is just normal VLAN setup.  Let's say VLAN 50.

On switch ports that are connected to iSCSI NAS, I'm pretty sure I would have to set the switch ports to VLAN 50.  I can enable NICs on iSCSI NAS to VLAN 50 as well (not sure if this is necessary).

At this point, I should be able to connect to iSCSI NAS from my LAN.

QUESTION : 
How about the ports that are connected to iSCSI HBAs on ESXi host?
Do I also set ports VLAN to 50?

I'm not sure if i'm on the right track on this.  I know best practice for iSCSI traffic is to isolate them, and introducing VLAN would degrade switching performance.
But then how would I manage iSCSI NAS and the switches?

Thanks for any comments.

UPDATE :
To clarify there's 2 things I want to manage - iSCSI NAS and switches

iSCSI NAS -> if I had a spare NIC on iSCSI NAS, then I can use that for management, connecting to my LAN.  But I don't.

switches -> I can connect and setup the mgmt ip on switches to my LAN subnet.  This allows me to manage the switches and keep iSCSI on it's own subnet... no need for VLAN.  Is this a safe practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should manage your switches and NAS through dedicated management ports, either they come that way or you setup a nic/port on a management VLAN.

This will keep the management traffic "isolated" and out of band of your iscsi traffic and allow you to make changes if necessary to the iscsi network remotely without having to be physically consoled into the switch, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a VM on your ESXi host (presumably it's vSphere and not ESXi). Configure the VM with a NIC connected to your management or production LAN and configure a NIC connected to the iSCSI LAN. RDP into the VM and manage the iSCSI components from there.